# How to redirect your app page directly to your fan page in facebook?

Tags: facebook, redirect, canvas

I'm totaly new in facebook development.

I've got a custom wordpress website. I created a facebook app in order to use facebook connect for my website.

I have also created a separate fan page.

I want this:

When the user finds my APP in search i want him to be redirected to the fanpage.
For example: `http://apps.facebook.com/uno` leads to the same place as `http://facebook.com/uno` with different urls.

Answer (score 0):

Have this in your canvas app:

```
<script>top.location.href='http://facebook.com/uno'</script>
```

This will redirect the "top" window to the page you specify.

Comment: I haven't actually created any app.I just used the tokens for facebook connect.should i just make a php with this content on my server and link my canvas there?

Comment: yes you can do that. Though, no need for "server-side" here. a simple html page would do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped loads.Just curious though how do uno manages to maintain the same address in the url bar afer the redirect?